# Android phone and HP printer connected to WPA-2 WLAN without ever asking for password

Tags: wireless-networking, security, printer, android

I recently bought a new printer (HP DeskJet) and a new smartphone (Samsung / Android v9). During installation and setup, both of these devices were able to connect to my home Wi-Fi and stay connected to it thereafter, without ever having asked for the password. All I had to do was select the network's SSID during the first few screens of each device's setup steps, and the phone/printer then connected to it straight away, no questions asked.

The network in question is WPA2-secured and runs 802.11n, through an ZTE router. If I try to connect to it with a PC or smartphone, it will ask for a password, as expected. The password is normal for the situation (around 20 digits or so, no letters or others chars).

Both the smartphone and the printer were brand new, and thus had never been used on this (or indeed any other) WiFi network previously.

I don't at all understand how they were able to connect to the network as if it had been unsecured. I am sure the protocols involved are different between the phone's and the printer's case (the former I imagine uses the network much more intensely), but the way the password was bypassed was bewilderingly similar for both.

Most of all, it's unclear to me what other devices could do the same, i.e. use the network without authorisation.

Does this mean the network's security has somehow been compromised and that I should reconfigure it? Or is something else going on that I don't understand? (am no expert in wireless networks)

Comment: You've had to perform some steps to connect them. What have you done exactly?

Comment: will update the question

Comment: Assuming when you talk of your network, you mean a router, are you sure UPNP has been disabled in the router?

Comment: Not sure of at all, in fact I don't recall setting this parameter one way or another. But surely by default it would be set so that not just anyone can use the network?

Comment: @z8080 If you previously connected to your WiFi on an Android phone, Google backs up that data so setting up a new device is easier (unsure if HP does the same, but sounds like it). As to your WPA2 passphrase, it's insecure if it's only numbers _(I cover the math [here](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/advice-needed-about-wifi-security/13188/32))_ and should contain at least 16 characters comprising of **at least** 2 uppercase, 2 lowercase, 2 numbers, and 2 symbols

Comment: @z8080  I know of routers that came with UPNP enabled by default.  They like to make things easier for you.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille UPnP has zero to do with authenticating to a WiFi network; UPnP auto-configures port redirects and should never be used as there's no invocation of UPnP that is secure. It's recommended to take the 30s and configure a port forward manually on the router, especially when there's only a handful of devices that require port redirects to work correctly, most dealing with gaming.

Comment: @JW0914 Why are you telling me?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille ??? Your previous comments

Comment: Was your new Android phone's cellular wireless data (4G/LTE) service working already? Did you sign into your Google account? If so, your Wi-Fi settings and passwords could have synched over from your Google account, which knew them because your old phone knew them. Then, if you used an Android app to set up your printer, that app probably transferred your Wi-Fi password from your phone to your printer.

Comment: @Spiff that's what I thought as well. I don't remember if the first WiFi connection took place before or after I signed in to my Google account on the new phone. Certainly them being retrieved from the old phone is an option, although I'd have expected that to take place during the subsequent Smart Switch operation, rather than before it. I think the UPNP option (vulnerability, if on by default?!) that Gerald mentioned might be more likely, will check that when I get the chance.

Comment: By default on Android Google syncs Wifi passwords into the cloud. Therefore it is no surprise that the new Android device was not asking for the Wifi password after you logged-in with your existing Google account. This behavior is described in the set-zup process, the Wifi password sync is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not at all sure I had logged in *prior* to the phone hooking itself to the WiFi. I'd incline to say I only did so afterwards. Also, it would not explain why the printer (who was not privvy to any Android-synced passwords) also just connected with no questions asked. TO me both these cases suggest the UPnP as the more likely explanation. Indeed, that feature was turned on (have now turned it off), even though the ShieldsUp! website was showing it to be off.